# how do i add a script to an aspx form in visual web developer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-web-developer-2010

I've searched the net and watched videos on this but no one really helps. What I want to do is add an already typed java script file to my aspx form in Visual web developer.
All tell me that i should just add:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title><title>
<script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

but....
in an aspx form theres no `<head>` or `<body>` tags only:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server" /> 
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" >
</asp:Content>
```

If even possible to add java script to this aspx form please give me the code or help me do this right.

I have a picture and i want a button to change the picture to the next one in the gallery on my web page

### Edit 1

Here is the html code to the buttons and picture

```
<tr>
    <td> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Prev" OnClientClick="init();"/> </td>
    <td> <img ID="pic" alt="" src="010.JPG" runat="server" width="200" height="200" /> </td>
    <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClientClick="init();"/> </td>
</tr>
```

And here is the code to the javascript init()

```
var imagePath = new Array();
var imageIndex = 0;

function init(){
     addPath("Bell.jpg");
     addPath("Dads.png");

     getImagePath(0);
}

function addPath(path){
     var index = imagePath.length;
     imagePath[index++] = path;  
}

function getImagePath(index){
     var length = imagePath.length;

     if(index <= length){
        if(index >= 0){
            document.getElementById("pic").src = imagePath[index];
            document.getElementById("pic").alt = imagePath[index];
            imageIndex = index;
        }
     } else {
        document.getElementById("pic").src = "DOES NOT EXIST";
        document.getElementById("pic").alt = "DOES NOT EXIST";
     }
}
```

it doesn't appear to be calling the javascript init() method however

The above is now solved thank you

### BUT Edit 2

the init function needs to run when you load the page before the buttons will know where to point the image source to. How can I call the init() when the page loads up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put here

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server" /> 
    <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

### Edit 1

```
function getImagePath(index){
     var length = imagePath.length;

     if(index <= length){
        if(index >= 0){
            document.getElementById("<%= pic.ClientID %>").src = imagePath[index];
            document.getElementById("<%= pic.ClientID %>").alt = imagePath[index];
            imageIndex = index;
        }
     } else {
        document.getElementById("<%= pic.ClientID %>").src = "DOES NOT EXIST";
        document.getElementById("<%= pic.ClientID %>").alt = "DOES NOT EXIST";
     }
}
```

Also

```
function init(){
      addPath("Bell.jpg");
      addPath("Dads.png");
      getImagePath(0);
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: I now get this error when trying to call the method from the button

Here's the button code:
        '<td> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Prev" OnClick="init()"/> </td>'

And here is the error message:
'Error 1 'ASP.gallery_2007_billfish_billfish_2007_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'init' and no extension method 'init' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.gallery_2007_billfish_billfish_2007_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Zelda\Desktop\WebProgramming\testWebSite002\Gallery\2007 BillFish\BillFish 2007.aspx'

Comment: the function `init()` is a server side function or javascript function. If it a server-side function then it should be `OnClick="init"`

Comment: now it's making an init() method in the .cs file but it already is in the javascript file and it gives me this error:

Error 2 Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or declaration statement

Comment: if it is a java script function so it should be on `onClientClick` as  `OnClientClick="init()"` rather than `OnClick="init()"`

Comment: it doesn't appear to be calling the javascript init() method

Comment: try simple alert as follows `OnClientClick="javascript:alert('testing');"`

Comment: when I try the alert thingy, it works and I get the message box but my init() method still isn't being called

Comment: try firebug and mozila firefox to get the error [here is a link](https://getfirebug.com/errors)

Comment: according to the firebug it does call and go through the method but just before it sets the pictures source it goes out of the function. I don't understand why it doesn't continue?

Comment: I found my problem

because it's a aspx and has these:

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" /> 
</asp:Content>
I needed to change the ID of the line where I do a lookup of the image pic

original document.getElementById("pic").alt = imagePath[index];

changed document.getElementById("MainContent_pic").alt = imagePath[index];

and now it can find the picture and change the source

Thanks for all the help

BUT I edited my original question because I now have yet another question

Comment: you can also use `<%= pic.ClientID %>` it will give you the same result. Kindly mark the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the script in your Content.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server" />
    <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </asp:Content>
```